# Issue with plots in ShinyApp and Windows

Tags: r, encoding, shiny

I am French and I am writing a ShinyApp which show a plot. When the temporary directory do not contains special characters, that works. But if the tempdir contains, for example, a 'ç' in the path, the app launches but the plot don't show.

My app contains two files ui.R and server.R and it is called in R console (not Rstudio where it works) with the function runApp)

Here is the ui.R

```
    ui = fluidPage(
      sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(),
       mainPanel(
          uiOutput('temp'),
          plotOutput("plot")
        )
      )
)
```

Here is the server.R

```
 server = function(input, output) {

    output$temp <- renderUI({
    p(tempdir())
    })


    output$plot <- renderPlot({
    cars2 <- cars
    plot(cars)
    })
    }
```

I already tried many tips :

- use of options(encoding='utf-8')

  - change the page code in DOS before launches the R console (with the command chcp)

I think the plot function does not find the temporary folder to create the png but I don't know how to fix this issue
Any idea ?

Thanks in advance

Best